# Can Django's development server route mutliple sites? If yes, how?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting with Django and want to try out the features of `django.contrib.sites`. I have added some aliases for `127.0.0.1` in my `/etc/hosts`, and can run different sites by providing a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` when running `manage.py runserver`.

What I haven't managed to do is to have both sites available at once, on the same port. I have seen solutions that use WSGI and Apache or similar, but none using the development server.

**Can the Django Development server serve multiple sites at once, switching by domain name, or is the nearest I'll get to start multiple servers on different ports?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

The `SITE_ID` is cached in various places, so you can't change it at runtime. You need a separate process for each site, but you can't bind more than one process to a single port. Neither can the development server act as a reverse proxy for separate processes.

Running each site on a different port is the closest you can get. This is what happens with any HTTP-based app server, but in a production environment you use a reverse proxy to forward all requests from port 80 to the appropriate port for that site.